# Use ethereum address from ledger nano S for participating in ICO

Tags: ledger-nano-s

I want to know if I can use the ethereum wallet addresses that come with the Nano S. I have eth on it and used this to participate in an ICO. Is that ok as it is first time using this address as it doesn't have a private key?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The list of all supported ERC20 tokens by the Ledger Nano S is at [this page](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005439585-ERC20-tokens-supported)

I'm not quoting this page because it is often updated, therefore my quote would be quickly missing important information.

If you just want to **receive** some ERC20 tokens you actually don't need to do anything special. Every Ethereum addresses have the same properties, no matters what wallet you're using.

With the Ledger Nano S and the Ledger App you won't be able to manage (to **send**) some non-supported tokens but don't worry, it doesn't mean you lost them. They are still there and you can check it by viewing your Ethereum address on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io) for example.

In order to **send** non-supported tokens you must connect your Ledger Nano S to MyEtherWallet as described [here](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005200009-How-to-use-MyEtherWallet-with-Ledger)